# How to get local address the kernel assign to a UDP socket with connect()?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, udpclient

Reading the [https://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Sockets-Networking/dp/0131411551](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551), chapter

*8.14 Determining Outgoing Interface with UDP*

> A connected UDP socket can also be used to determine the outgoing interface that will
> be used to a particular destination. This is because of a side effect of the connect
> function when applied to a UDP socket: The kernel chooses the local IP address
> (assuming the process has not already called bind to explicitly assign this). This local
> IP address is chosen by searching the routing table for the destination IP address, and
> then using the primary IP address for the resulting interface.

If I try to run the example (*udpcli01.c*):

```
#define BSIZE 256
#define SERV_PORT 9877

typedef struct sockaddr SA;

//argv[1] = ip address
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd;
    socklen_t servlen, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
    char ip[BSIZE];

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        die("usage: %s <ip>\n", argv[0]);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    servlen = sizeof(servaddr);
    memset(&servaddr, 0, servlen);
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr);

    connect(sockfd, (SA *)&servaddr, servlen);

    clilen = sizeof(clilen);
    if (getsockname(sockfd, (SA *)&cliaddr, &clilen) < 0)
    {
        perror("getsockname");
    }

    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr, ip, BSIZE);
    printf("address %s:%hd\n", ip, cliaddr.sin_port);
}
```

Now If i run the server in one terminal (which address `INADDR_ANY` and port `9877`), and then run the client above:

```
terminal 1:
$ ./udpserv01

terminal 2:
$ #I will try localhost first
$ ./udpcli01 127.0.0.1
address 2.0.178.211:-11342
$ #did not work, now my host ip 10.0.0.11
$ ./udpcli01 10.0.0.11
address 2.0.193.86:22209
```

I always get some garbage even if the client is prior to printing its address and port, connected to server, which is listening. If i was trying to print server address and port, then it would work (that is, it would print `127.0.0.1:9877` and `10.0.0.11:9877` respectively -> I have already tried). So I know the `inet_ntop` is working correctly and also getting the port number. So where is issue in the client? Does the kernel really assigns address and port upon `connect()` according to the book? If so then why my example prints random garbage?

```
uname -a:
Linux Shepherd 5.8.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 5 21:54:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The [POSIX documentation for `connect()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html) does state:  "If the socket has not already been bound to a local address, `connect()` shall bind it to an address which, unless the socket's address family is `AF_UNIX`, is an unused local address." So you seem to have found something wrong. What OS are you using?  What are **all** the IP address(es) assigned to your system?  And port values are `unsigned short` in network byte order.

Comment: @AndrewHenle see edits. 1) using linux, 2) I have no idea how to find out what adresses are assigned to my system. 3) yes, my mistake, I forgot to use `ntohs()` to convert ports. But the address are garbage anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the address of a `struct sockaddr_in` to the `inet_ntop` function.  For an `AF_INET` socket it expects a pointer to a `struct in_addr`.

So instead of this:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr, ip, BSIZE);
```

You want this:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, ip, BSIZE);
```

Also, be sure to call `ntohs` on the `sin_port` member before you print it to get the proper value, and use `%d` instead of `%hd`:

```
printf("address %s:%d\n", ip, ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));
```

And `clilen` is not initialized properly:

```
clilen = sizeof(clilen);
```

It should be:

```
clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
```

Comment: Now, after changes you suggest, both `./udpcli01 127.0.0.1` or `./udpcli01 10.0.0.11` gives output `address 0.0.0.0:-23170`. The address is always `0.0.0.0` and the port is still some garbage (even with `ntohs()`), I assume that is no what the book is showing. So what is the true solution?

Comment: @milanHrabos For the port, use `%d` instead of `%hd` as the latter expects a `signed short`.  The address is correct because you didn't bind to a specific IP.

Comment: I don't bind, just as is at book. They say side effect of the *connect* function to assign (not previously bind) the adress by kernel. So I should not have *0.0.0.0* because I `connect()` (and the kernel should give me one). So your comment is in contradiction of the book.

Comment: @milanHrabos Ah, it seems there was another problem.  `clilen` wasn't set correctly.